# What's the meaning of square brackets [ ] in WiX?

Tags: iis, wix, windows-installer

I'm creating an installer for an IIS website using the WiX toolset and I use [this](http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-3/) manual. I've came across the following syntax:

```
<iis:WebSite Id="DemoWebsiteWebsite" Description='Demo Website' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' AutoStart='yes' StartOnInstall='yes'>
  <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
  <iis:WebApplication Id="DemoWebsiteApplication" Name="[DemoWebsiteWebsite][WEBSITE_ID]" WebAppPool="DemoWebsiteAppPool"></iis:WebApplication>
</iis:WebSite>
```

I'm confused by the `[]` syntax and the way website id is used here. I need to use some custom values entered by user for that. So I have the following questions:

1. What does the `[]` syntax mean in WiX? How is it related to the `$()` syntax that is used to access the defined value?
2. Is there any additional meaning for two `[]` following each other like here `[DemoWebsiteWebsite][WEBSITE_ID]`?
3. Why the WebSite Id is used in `[DemoWebsiteWebsite]` expression? Is that just a coincidence or naming convention?
4. What are the allowed values to be used inside `[]`? Is there any kind of list for them?
5. Where can I find additional info about this syntax and cases it is used for?

Comment: Short answer: It doesn't mean anything to WiX. @PhilDW's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23939543/2226988) explains what they mean to Windows Installer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the way that Windows Installer properties are resolved to the actual values. If you entered a property called WEBSITE into an MSI dialog you'd get that resolved to the actual value by putting it in square brackets. That's why you see things like [TARGETDIR], [SourceDir] and so on. The syntax is used in most tools that generate MSI files because it's a Windows Installer thing.

This is the doc link, it's all hidden here:

[Formatted Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So 1 - they are properties in the MSI file, either standard Windows Installer properties or user-created ones:

[Property Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and 2, they are just two properties concatenated. They are case-sensitive so don't be sloppy with the case. The other points should be clear after understanding that they are installer properties.

The $() values in WiX source are compile time - they resolve at build time to actual values. The [] values resolve at install time.

Comment: That looks like a much better explanation! Could you please extend it by answering all the items 1-5 with more details?

Comment: Now it really almost completelly clear except of one thing - 3 - why the WebSite Id is used in [DemoWebsiteWebsite] expression? Is that just a coincidence or somewhere there is a Property defined that corresponds WebsiteId? If yes, to what value does it evaluates?

Comment: By definition if there is a property in brackets like that then there must be something somewhere that creates that property, and a WiX build will error if it can't find a reference. The difficulty is that you can create properties just by specifying them, including on an msiexec command line, and there's no list of the default value for user-defined properties unless they are in the Property table of the MSI file, using the Property Id element in WiX.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! I'll try to use Orca software to determine, what is the value of that property then. If I'll not find it in Property table - I'll then just try to determine it in runtime

Comment: The !() syntax is useful to know about as well. Those are resolved at link time, and can be used to extract properties of linked files. See: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html

Comment: @PhilDW The build will not fail because there is no attempt to resolve property references where formatted properties are used. After all, the property could be passed on the command-line. It need not otherwise have been created.